# human IK control rig not moving (Maya)

Tags: controls, maya

So I have a serious problem with Maya 2016. I have a character which uses the Human IK rig. Now all of a sudden some of the controllers for the Rig don't move or rotate. This is an issue only in my PC. When I transfer the file to any other PC the Rig, it can be controlled.

Previously I had Maya 2014 installed and I was told that Maya could possibly be reading the wrong file settings etc. So I first uninstalled all Maya versions and cleared out all the Autodesk folders from the Program data and documents folders. Then deleted all registry for Autodesk. And re-installed Maya. But this didn't help.

So I took the extreme step of formatting the whole PC and then installing Maya only. Still the same Smiley Sad

Anyone have any idea on why or how to solve this?

Comment: Did you tried to clean out your preference ? ~/user/maya ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my Human IK where only the feet and hips would move, after messing around with it I found that if you go to the Character Controls, Control rig, some of the spheres representing the handles were Grey, while the one's that work are green. If you select each handle in the controls menu at the bottom are three sliders for Blend T, Blend R, and Pull. If you max the sliders for the blends the sphere should turn green and the handle should work. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I found out that simply going into the Human IK controls and clicking the button called Full Body on the top of the windows, enables the whole movent again.